# When using AngularJS cache in a http get request, even newly added data is not showing in a list / table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 questions.

**Question #1**

I have a AngularJS application which manage more than 5000+ rows data tables.
I used AngularJS `cache` library to manage these data.

`$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);`

For example, I added `cache` for customers view request. My issue is when I add a new customer, it's saving in the database. But because of the `cache` , it's not showing in the list.

Is there any way to disable `cache` temporary when we add a new entry ? 
Or how we can manage this ? Is there a way to detect new entry adding and disabling `cache` as soon as we are loading the list views ?

**Question #2**

I'm using basic HTML table to display all the rows. For now, there are like 5000+ records. This number is increasing monthly. What is the best way to manage this much of a data table in AngularJS ?

I'm researching on [UI GRID for AngularJS](http://ui-grid.info/). Please let me is there any better options to manage big data tables in AngularJS ?

Comment: It's probably best you post these as two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you manage the variable yourself:

```
var cacheEnabled = true;
$http.get(url, { cache: cacheEnabled}).success(...);
// some things happen
cacheEnabled = false;
$http.get(url, { cache: cacheEnabled}).success(...);
```

For the second part of the question, I suggest you do server side pagination or else the clients accesing your web page are going to suffer heavily.